# Calculating median - javascript

Tags: javascript, median

I've been trying to calculate **median** but still I've got some mathematical issues I guess as I couldn't get the correct median value and couldn't figure out why. Here's the code;

```
class StatsCollector {

    constructor() {
        this.inputNumber = 0;
        this.average = 0;

        this.timeout = 19000;

        this.frequencies = new Map();
        for (let i of Array(this.timeout).keys()) {
            this.frequencies.set(i, 0);
        }
    }

    pushValue(responseTimeMs) {
        let req = responseTimeMs;
        if (req > this.timeout) {
            req = this.timeout;
        }

        this.average = (this.average * this.inputNumber + req) / (this.inputNumber + 1);

        console.log(responseTimeMs / 1000)
        let groupIndex = Math.floor(responseTimeMs / 1000);
        this.frequencies.set(groupIndex, this.frequencies.get(groupIndex) + 1);

        this.inputNumber += 1;
    }

    getMedian() {
        let medianElement = 0;
        if (this.inputNumber <= 0) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (this.inputNumber == 1) {
            return this.average
        }
        if (this.inputNumber == 2) {
            return this.average
        }
        if (this.inputNumber > 2) {
            medianElement = this.inputNumber / 2;
        }

        let minCumulativeFreq = 0;
        let maxCumulativeFreq = 0;
        let cumulativeFreq = 0;
        let freqGroup = 0;
        for (let i of Array(20).keys()) {
            if (medianElement <= cumulativeFreq + this.frequencies.get(i)) {
                minCumulativeFreq = cumulativeFreq;
                maxCumulativeFreq = cumulativeFreq + this.frequencies.get(i);
                freqGroup = i;
                break;
            }
            cumulativeFreq += this.frequencies.get(i);
        }

        return (((medianElement - minCumulativeFreq) / (maxCumulativeFreq - minCumulativeFreq)) + (freqGroup)) * 1000;
    }

    getAverage() {
        return this.average;
    }

}
```

Here's the snapshot of the results when I enter the values of

> 342,654,987,1093,2234,6243,7087,20123

[image]

The correct result should be;

> Median: 1663.5

Comment: maybe look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305640/find-median-values-from-array-in-javascript-8-values-or-9-values)

Comment: To calculate the median, you have to sort the values and pick the middle one.

Comment: That's not a median.  The median should be in the set.

Comment: My first guess would be that you have a rounding error.

Comment: The Median is the middle number of the sorted list if there are a odd number of values, if there are an even number the median is the mid point or average of the central two values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [find median values from array in javascript (8 values or 9 values)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305640/find-median-values-from-array-in-javascript-8-values-or-9-values)

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Change your median method to this:

```js
function median(values: number[]): number {

  if (values.length === 0) {
    throw new Error('Input array is empty');
  }

  // Sorting values, preventing original array
  // from being mutated.
  values = [...values].sort((a, b) => a - b);

  const half = Math.floor(values.length / 2);

  return (values.length % 2
    ? values[half]
    : (values[half - 1] + values[half]) / 2
  );

}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zgtne5s6/)

Comment: what happens when `values.length ===0`?
I recommend a safe check at the first line `if(values.length ===0) return 0`

Comment: You do not need the `else`

Comment: Note that this method modifies the given array.

Comment: I think the median of an empty array is not 0, but undefined.

Comment: To preserve the given array, use something like `values = [...values];` at the function start.

Comment: Does NOT work with median([-0.51182868190794402, 0.33955843791573237, 1.073205764212215])

Comment: (I checked, it does work with it...)

Comment: This function should `if (!values.length) return NaN;` and `values.slice().sort(...)` to spare users bugs in their code.

Answer (score 63):

Here's another solution:

```js
function median(numbers) {
    const sorted = Array.from(numbers).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const middle = Math.floor(sorted.length / 2);

    if (sorted.length % 2 === 0) {
        return (sorted[middle - 1] + sorted[middle]) / 2;
    }

    return sorted[middle];
}

console.log(median([4, 5, 7, 1, 33]));
```

Comment: Good, this keeps the original array unmodified.

Comment: I know that I am 2 years late but this answer is better than the other ones at the top.

Comment: A check for the length of the argument array being greater or equal to two is missing.

Comment: @FilipIlievski indeed this assumes valid inputs. We could also verify that the input is actually an Array (length can be set on objects), that the elements are numbers, etc.

Comment: @JBallin yes, valid points :) I come from TypeScript, so a bit less to worry about once you properly define your types. ✌️

Answer (score 16):

## 2024 TypeScript Approach

```
const median = (arr: number[]): number | undefined => {
  if (!arr.length) return undefined;
  const s = [...arr].sort((a, b) => a - b);
  const mid = Math.floor(s.length / 2);
  return s.length % 2 ? s[mid] : ((s[mid - 1] + s[mid]) / 2);
};
```

Notes:

- The type in the function signature (`number[]`) ensures only an array of numbers can be passed to the function. It could possibly be empty though.
- `if (!arr.length) return undefined;` checks for the possible empty array, which would not have a median.
- `[...arr]` creates a copy of the passed-in array to ensure we don't overwrite the original.
- `.sort((a, b) => a - b)` sorts the array of numbers in ascending order.
- `Math.floor(s.length / 2)` finds the index of the middle element if the array has odd length, or the element just to the right of the middle if the array has even length.
- `s.length % 2` determines whether the array has an even length.
- `(s[mid - 1] + s[mid]) / 2` averages the two middle items of the array if the array's length is even.
- `s[mid]` is the middle item of an odd-length array.

Comment: This should be upvoted. Definitely best answer. Also [version for javascript](https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/fundamental/javascript-fundamental-exercise-88.php).

Comment: In 2024 I would recommend using `Array.prototype.toSorted()` instead of manually copying the array for immutability

Answer (score 13):

The solutions above - sort then find middle - are fine, but slow on large data sets. Sorting the data first has a complexity of n x log(n).

There is a faster median algorithm, which consists in segregating the array in two according to a pivot, then looking for the median in the larger set. Here is some javascript code, but [here is a more detailed explanation](https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding)

```js
// Trying some array
alert(quickselect_median([7,3,5])); // 2300,5,4,0,123,2,76,768,28]));

function quickselect_median(arr) {
   const L = arr.length, halfL = L/2;
   if (L % 2 == 1)
      return quickselect(arr, halfL);
   else
      return 0.5 * (quickselect(arr, halfL - 1) + quickselect(arr, halfL));
}

function quickselect(arr, k) {
   // Select the kth element in arr
   // arr: List of numerics
   // k: Index
   // return: The kth element (in numerical order) of arr
   if (arr.length == 1)
      return arr[0];
   else {
      const pivot = arr[0];
      const lows = arr.filter((e)=>(e<pivot));
      const highs = arr.filter((e)=>(e>pivot));
      const pivots = arr.filter((e)=>(e==pivot));
      if (k < lows.length) // the pivot is too high
         return quickselect(lows, k);
      else if (k < lows.length + pivots.length)// We got lucky and guessed the median
         return pivot;
      else // the pivot is too low
         return quickselect(highs, k - lows.length - pivots.length);
   }
}
```

Astute readers will notice a few things:

1. I simply transliterated Russel Cohen's Python solution into JS,
   so all kudos to him.
2. There are several small optimisations worth
   doing, but there's parallelisation worth doing, and the code as is
   is easier to change in either a quicker single-threaded, or quicker
   multi-threaded, version.
3. This is the *average linear time*
   algorithm, there is more efficient a *deterministic* linear time version, see [Russel's
   post](https://rcoh.me/posts/linear-time-median-finding) for details, including performance data.

ADDITION 19 Sept. 2019:

One comment asks whether this is worth doing in javascript. I ran the code in [JSPerf](https://jsperf.com/fast-median) and it gives interesting results.

- if the array has an odd number of elements (one figure to find), sorting is 20% slower that this "fast median" proposition.
- if there is an even number of elements, the "fast" algorithm is 40% slower, because it filters through the data twice, to find elements number k and k+1 to average. It is possible to write a version of fast median that doesn't do this.

The test used rather small arrays (29 elements in the jsperf test). The effect appears to be more pronounced as arrays get larger. A more general point to make is: it shows these kinds of optimisations are worth doing in Javascript. An awful lot of computation is done in JS, including with large amounts of data (think of dashboards, spreadsheets, data visualisations), and in systems with limited resources (think of mobile and embedded computing).

Comment: I'm trying to understand wether it makes sense for javascript. This quickselect algorithm seems to be trying to implement a Quicksort algorithm by hand. In javascript the type of sort algorithm depending on the size of array and the browser too. When you use Array.sort() an optimized sort algorithm is chosen in the background. I coube be mistaken, off course, what do you think about it ?

Comment: My answer is probably a product of my bend as a computing *educator*, more than *practitioner* - I teach the thing, so there's a fantastic lesson in this. Whether the algorithm above is a good idea depends on why you're doing this, as always. How big, the arrays? Are lots of them? Will you need the data sorted at some point, or need other stats like quartiles etc? do you use other libraries that change the tool selection? Is time performance a big factor to you? Is resources a big factor to you?

Comment: @ThiagoC.SVentura your comment prompted to test if the difference would be visible in JSPerf. I add the results to the answer.

Answer (score 6):

```
var arr = {  
  max: function(array) {
    return Math.max.apply(null, array);
  },
  
  min: function(array) {
    return Math.min.apply(null, array);
  },
  
  range: function(array) {
    return arr.max(array) - arr.min(array);
  },
  
  midrange: function(array) {
    return arr.range(array) / 2;
  },

  sum: function(array) {
    var num = 0;
    for (var i = 0, l = array.length; i < l; i++) num += array[i];
    return num;
  },
  
  mean: function(array) {
    return arr.sum(array) / array.length;
  },
  
  median: function(array) {
    array.sort(function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    });
    var mid = array.length / 2;
    return mid % 1 ? array[mid - 0.5] : (array[mid - 1] + array[mid]) / 2;
  },
  
  modes: function(array) {
    if (!array.length) return [];
    var modeMap = {},
      maxCount = 1,
      modes = [array[0]];

    array.forEach(function(val) {
      if (!modeMap[val]) modeMap[val] = 1;
      else modeMap[val]++;

      if (modeMap[val] > maxCount) {
        modes = [val];
        maxCount = modeMap[val];
      }
      else if (modeMap[val] === maxCount) {
        modes.push(val);
        maxCount = modeMap[val];
      }
    });
    return modes;
  },
  
  variance: function(array) {
    var mean = arr.mean(array);
    return arr.mean(array.map(function(num) {
      return Math.pow(num - mean, 2);
    }));
  },
  
  standardDeviation: function(array) {
    return Math.sqrt(arr.variance(array));
  },
  
  meanAbsoluteDeviation: function(array) {
    var mean = arr.mean(array);
    return arr.mean(array.map(function(num) {
      return Math.abs(num - mean);
    }));
  },
  
  zScores: function(array) {
    var mean = arr.mean(array);
    var standardDeviation = arr.standardDeviation(array);
    return array.map(function(num) {
      return (num - mean) / standardDeviation;
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for copy-pasting the whole library, but where does this come from?

Comment: Again, this median function will modify the input array when it sorts it. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Does anyone know if these are fast?  These are very helpful.

Comment: @jboxxx Yes they are fast I have tested it. I used in LeetCode in one algorithem the results were : 
Runtime: 159 ms, faster than 59.70% of JavaScript online submissions for Median of Two Sorted Arrays.
Memory Usage: 47 MB, less than 71.82% of JavaScript online submissions for Median of Two Sorted Arrays.

Answer (score 3):

```
const median = (arr) => {
  return arr.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.floor(arr.length / 2)];
};
```

Comment: This method will give incorrect results `[1,2,3,4]` results in `3` while it should be `2.5`

Comment: @Mohsen Alyafei You're talking about average not median.

Comment: No. Average would be 5. Median would be 2.5. Average is total divided by 2. Median is the middle number. If no middle number then the 2 numbers on the side divided by 2.

Answer (score 2):

**TypeScript Answer 2020:**

```
// Calculate Median 
const calculateMedian = (array: Array<number>) => {
  // Check If Data Exists
  if (array.length >= 1) {
    // Sort Array
    array = array.sort((a: number, b: number) => {
      return a - b;
    });

    // Array Length: Even
    if (array.length % 2 === 0) {
      // Average Of Two Middle Numbers
      return (array[(array.length / 2) - 1] + array[array.length / 2]) / 2;
    }
    // Array Length: Odd
    else {
      // Middle Number
      return array[(array.length - 1) / 2];
    }
  }
  else {
    // Error
    console.error('Error: Empty Array (calculateMedian)');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Short and sweet.

```
Array.prototype.median = function () {
  return this.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.floor(this.length / 2)]; 
};
```

Usage

```
[4, 5, 7, 1, 33].median()
```

Works with strings as well

```
["a","a","b","b","c","d","e"].median()
```

Comment: `[0, 5].median()` produces 5 as a result

Comment: DON'T MUTATE PROTOTYPES.

Comment: const median = (a) => a.slice().sort((a, b) => a - b)[Math.floor(a.length / 2)];

Answer (score 0):

For better performance in terms of time complexity, use (MaxHeap - MinHeap) to find the median of stream of array.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler & more efficient

```
const median = dataSet => {
  if (dataSet.length === 1) return dataSet[0]
  const sorted = ([ ...dataSet ]).sort()
  const ceil = Math.ceil(sorted.length / 2)
  const floor = Math.floor(sorted.length / 2)
  if (ceil === floor) return sorted[floor]
  return ((sorted[ceil] + sorted[floor]) / 2)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```js
function calcMedian(array) {
  const {
    length
  } = array;

  if (length < 1)
    return 0;

  //sort array asc
  array.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  if (length % 2) {
    //length of array is odd
    return array[(length + 1) / 2 - 1];
  } else {
    //length of array is even
    return 0.5 * [(array[length / 2 - 1] + array[length / 2])];
  }
}

console.log(2, calcMedian([1, 2, 2, 5, 6]));
console.log(3.5, calcMedian([1, 2, 2, 5, 6, 7]));
console.log(9, calcMedian([13, 9, 8, 15, 7]));
console.log(3.5, calcMedian([1, 4, 6, 3]));
console.log(5, calcMedian([5, 1, 11, 2, 8]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Simpler, more efficient, and easy to read

1. cloned the data to avoid alterations to the original data.
2. sort the list of values.
3. get the middle point.
4. get the median from the list.
5. return the median.

```js
function getMedian(data) {
    const values = [...data];
    const v   = values.sort( (a, b) => a - b);
    const mid = Math.floor( v.length / 2);
    const median = (v.length % 2 !== 0) ? v[mid] : (v[mid - 1] + v[mid]) / 2; 
    return median;
}
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. You can edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28443910)

Comment: You write "simpler & more efficient", but it would be good to know what you compare with, since many have already answered with similar code. Essentially the `sort` operation determines the execution time, and most answers have used that.

Comment: Doesn't work console.log(getMedian([-0.51182868190794402, 0.33955843791573237, 1.073205764212215]));

Answer (score 0):

```js
       const medianArr = (x) => {
        let sortedx = x.sort((a,b)=> a-b);
        let halfIndex = Math.floor(sortedx.length/2);
        
         return (sortedx.length%2) ? (sortedx[Math.floor(sortedx.length/2)]) :  ((sortedx[halfIndex-1]+sortedx[halfIndex])/2)
    }
    
    console.log(medianArr([1,2,3,4,5]));
    console.log(medianArr([1,2,3,4,5,6]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function Median(arr){
    let len = arr.length;
    arr = arr.sort();
    let result = 0;
    let mid = Math.floor(len/2);
    if(len % 2 !== 0){
        result += arr[mid];
    }
    if(len % 2 === 0){
        result += (arr[mid] + arr[mid+1])/2
    }
    return result;
    
}

console.log(`The median is ${Median([0,1,2,3,4,5,6])}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function median(arr) {
    let n = arr.length;
    let med = Math.floor(n/2);
    if(n % 2 != 0){
       return arr[med];
    } else{
       return (arr[med -1] + arr[med])/ 2.0
    }
 }
 console.log(median[1,2,3,4,5,6]);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The `arr.sort()` method sorts the elements of an array in place and returns the array. By default, it sorts the elements alphabetically, so if the array contains numbers, they will not be sorted in numerical order.
On the other hand, the `arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)` method uses a callback function to specify how the array should be sorted. The callback function compares the two elements `a` and `b` and returns a negative number if a should be sorted before `b`, a positive number if `b` should be sorted before `a`, and zero if the elements are equal. In this case, the callback function subtracts `b` from `a`, which results in a sorting order that is numerical in ascending order.

So, if you want to sort an array of numbers in ascending order, you should use `arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)`, whereas if you want to sort an array of strings alphabetically, you can use `arr.sort()`:

```
function median(numbers) {
    const sorted = Array.from(numbers).sort((a, b) => a - b);
    const middle = Math.floor(sorted.length / 2);

    if (sorted.length % 2 === 0) {
        return (sorted[middle - 1] + sorted[middle]) / 2;
    }

    return sorted[middle];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function findMedian(arr) {
  arr.sort((a, b) => a - b)

  let i = Math.floor(arr.length / 2)
  return arr[i]
}

let result = findMedian([0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 5, 3])
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Your answer is broken. Please fix it. Please also add an explanation. Code-only answers are likely to be flagged as low-quality by review.