# jquery median from two integer value (its not an array)

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to get median from two integer like :

I have simple value of  minimum and maximum ::=> 25 and 55,

so median from 25 to 55 will be around `37.5`, its ok if we got `38` as we need integer

How can I find using jQuery of javascript ?

Comment: `parseInt((parseFloat(a)+parseFloat(b))/2))` or if a,b already checked as numeric, just:
`parseInt((a+b)/2)`

Comment: I think this is more of a math problem than a programming

Comment: how do you get the value of `37.5`? the average is `40` ...

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25305640/find-median-values-from-array-in-javascript-8-values-or-9-values

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `bitwise right shift` operator for integer division it will always give the result as an integer value only.

```js
var num1 = 25;
var num2 = 58;
var result = (num1+num2)>>1;
console.log(result);
```